# CSS border issue

Tags: html, css

I dunno what's wrong with my css, but I can see only 50-60% of right border of left sidebar navigation. How to resize it to fit full container height? 
Here is the image of sidebar navigation
And link http://www.smiths-heimann.az/?page=2

[image]

Comment: the left side border is not coming through your left navigation it's border of the div that has class **content** and the height of that div limiting the border.

Comment: tried to do it with right border of #left and with left border of #content. Both failed

Answer (score 0):

There is a huge padding-bottom in your container div which is 373px. I guess you have to recheck the design. A quick solution can be to reduce this padding to 354px.

Comment: that's sticky footer trick. http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/ Take a look at footer css.

Comment: this is a simple design, but it messed up. i guess your tricks did that.

Answer (score 0):

You have a big mess with margins and paddings.
You should remove min-height on #wrap. Remove the negative margin-top on the #footer, the padding-bottom on the #container and just work on the padding-bottom of the .content

Comment: that's sticky footer trick. cssstickyfooter.com Take a look at footer css. Do you know any other solution to stick footer to the bottom of the page in any condition?

Comment: did you try position:absolute, bottom:0?

Comment: it will absolutely stick it, i mean  i wanna stuck to the bottom of the page even when thin on content. Otherwise it would be floating halfway up the page.

Comment: I think you should put another div between #container and #footer, and apply the trick on it. The .content must be of the same height of the container if you want the border to get 100%. If you apply some padding to the bottom of the #container the .content won't be 100%.

Comment: there is negative margin that full compensates padding

Comment: The negative margin is on the footer and does not influence the .content height.

Answer (score 0):

try setting you content div to "height:100%"